# When using ngFor in Angular 2, is it possible to not wrap component content with component selector tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to display table of users. Every `<tr>` tag is described by `UserRowComponent`:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'user-row',
   template: `
       <tr>
           <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
       </tr>
   `
})
```

For loop over users I'm using:

```
<tr>
   <!-- head of tabe -->
   <th>...<th>
   ....
</tr>
<user-row *ngFor="let user of users" [user]="user">
```

But as a result I get table with multiple `<user-row></user-row>` tags with `<tr>` tag inside.

There is a solution - set `selector` property to something like `tr.user-row` and remove wrpapping `<tr>` tag from `<user-row>` template.

But what if I need to show list of orders for each user in the same table, right after `<user-row>` like this:

```
<tr>...user-1 row...</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Order id</td>
    <td>Order date</td>
    <td>Order amount</td>
</tr>
<tr>...user-1 order-1 row ...</tr>
<tr>...user-1 order-2 row ...</tr>
<!-- user-2 with orders
     user-3 with orders
     etc.
-->
```

So it would be great to use `*ngFor` to display only content from `template` property, withot wrapping with selector tag. The template of component would be written in this way:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'user-row',
   template: `
       <tr>
           <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
       </tr>
       <user-orders-list [orders]="user.orders">
   `
})
```

And template of `<user-order-list>`:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'user-row',
   template: `
       <tr>
           <td>Order id</td>
           <td>Order date</td>
           <td>Order amount</td>
       </tr>
      <user-order-row *ngFor="let order of orders" [order]="order">
   `
})
```

Template for `<user-order-row>`:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'user-order-row',
   template: `
       <tr>
           <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ order.date }}</td>
           <td>{{ order.amount }}</td>
       </tr>
   `
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the template tag here. Style and format the way you want, of course. This probably won't make sense, so I [forked and modified a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4KgwhvjHIX5Hb2OoWqCL?p=preview) for you.

```
<table>
      <template let-user ngFor [ngForOf]="users">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let order of user.orders">
          <td>{{order.id}}</td>
          <td>{{order.date}}</td>
          <td>{{order.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </table>
```